# [iPhone]How to switch screens by touch and drag?

Tags: iphone, touch

I want to make a iPhone application which can switch screens by touch and drag, follow below picture:
[image]

Please guide for me!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this sample code from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PageControl/index.html

Comment: Thank for your guide!
But this use PageControl to switch screens, I want to manual switch screens (don't use PageControl or any). Do you have solution?

Comment: Look at the sample code. You don't have to use the actual page control. The sample code shows you how to use a UIScrollView to do this.